# How find String in a String not include Tag?

Tags: .net, vb.net

```
 Dim strTextTag="Terminology <VN_CR NO="1"/>for test in the glossary. Terminology <VN_F NO="1"><VN_CR NO="2"/></VN_F>for test"
 Dim strText="Terminology for test in the glossary. Terminology for test"
 Dim strValue="Terminology for test"
```

How do I firstly:
remove [`<VN_CR NO="1"/>`] and [`<VN_F NO="1"><VN_CR NO="2"/></VN_F>`] before searching.

Then how do I get the position of all `strValue` in `strTextTag` if `strValue` exist in `strText` ?

Comment: Your question is not clear and shows no evidence of research. Do you mean you want to find each index of strValue within strText? Have you tried looking at reference articles such as this: http://www.dotnetperls.com/indexof-vbnet ?

Comment: Yes, i want find strValue in strText, but i want [Terminology <VN_CR NO="1"/>for test] is ok.

Comment: Do you mean you want strValue = "[Terminology <VN_CR NO="1"/>for test]" ???

Comment: No,strValue="Terminology for test", find in strText not exist Tag,

Answer (score -1):

You can use `RegEx.Replace` to find and remove all tags. And use `Regex.Matches` function to find all occurrences of one string in another.

```
Function RemoveTags(ByVal textWithTags As String) As String
    Dim result As String = Regex.Replace(textWithTags, "<[^>]+?>", " ") '-- remove the tags
    result = result.Replace("  ", " ")      '-- remove any extra whitespaces that might have got in due to regex replacement
    Return result
End Function

Function GetTextPositions(ByVal text As String, ByVal find As String) As Integer()
    Dim result As New List(Of Integer)
    Dim re As New Regex(Regex.Escape(find))
    For Each match As Match In re.Matches(text)
        result.Add(match.Index)
    Next
    Return result.ToArray
End Function
```

Comment: Remove Tag to search , but get Position on textWithTags.

Comment: Just updated GetTextPositions function my answer to return all occurrences of text in string.